# The effect of additional $_POST[] variables in server performance

Tags: php, html

Please see the  following simple code.

```
<?php
$a = $_POST['a'];
$b = $_POST['b'];
$c = $_POST['c'];
$d = $_POST['d'];
$e = $_POST['e'];
......  ?>
```

And in `html` file we have only the following fields:

```
<form action="file.php" method="POST">
<p>A</p> <input type="text" name="a">
<p>B</p> <input type="text" name="b">
</form>
```

the above `html` code we have only two fields  but in the `php` file we have several `$_POST[]` variables and the global variables are more than the fields in `html` code. Now I want to know the additional `$_POST[]` variables values.

Is the value as the `""` (empty string)? Does the web server crash? Perhaps my question is simple but it is for me ambiguous.

Comment: The post comes from before the page you are looking at, they cant just magically appear.  Not to mention there is a 1000 index limit on them, which is far less then any decent server can handle, and is there for other reasons I wont get into in this short comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$_POST['c']`,... are not set so you get a `NOTICE`. (Their value are `null`)

it is better to change your code to something like:

```
if(isset($_POST['c'])) $c=$_POST['c']; else $c='';
```

or

```
$c=isset($_POST['c'])?$_POST['c']:'';
```

Answer (score 1):

To know any variable status try [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php):

```
var_dump($_POST['d']);
```

will output what you need.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to check : `var_dump($_POST)`

are

```
    $_POST['c'];
    $_POST['d'];
    $_POST['e'];
```

empty? or may be `c,d,e` are hidden variable sent from that form.

if your form is not sending `c,d,e` you'll most probabely going to get  `Notice: Undefined index:  in`

if not , remove those variables

Answer (score 0):

See `$_POST` is a global variable but its a array.

when you submit your form via `POST method` then you get post variable with a limited time period as the page changes all your previous post variable are gone.

If you are posting a form

see all post data using

```
  print_r($_POST);
```

or

```
 var_dump($_POST);
```

it gives a human readable array of post data. which will tell you what is in `$_POST`